# NoReverseMatch exception while resetting password in django using django's default views

Tags: python, django

I am getting the below error when I am using the 'ResetMyPassword' button

```
Reverse for 'password_reset_confirm' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{'uidb64': b'MTI', 'token': '48i-a406f922c705599d2c1e'}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['blog/resetpassword/(?P<uidb36>[0-9A-Za-z]+)-(?P<token>,+)/$']
```

Please find my urls.py below

```
from django.conf.urls import url, patterns
from django.contrib.auth.views import *
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^home$', views.home, name = 'blog_home'),
    url(r'^newpost$', views.new_post, name = 'blog_new_post'),
    url(r'^login$', views.login_user, name = 'blog_login'),
    url(r'^logout$', views.logout_user, name = 'blog_logout'),
    url(r'^register$', views.register_user, name = 'blog_register'),
    url(r'^resetpassword/passwordsent/$', password_reset_done, name = 'password_reset_done'),
    url(r'^resetpassword/$', password_reset, name = 'password_reset'),
    url(r'^resetpassword/(?P<uidb36>[0-9A-Za-z]+)-(?P<token>,+)/$', password_reset_confirm, name = 'password_reset_confirm'),
    url(r'^reset/done/$', password_reset_complete, name = 'password_reset_complete'),
```

]

Comment: Show us a template with a form, please.

Comment: Your pattern for `token` has a comma instead of a dot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `password_reset_confirm` URL pattern is out of date. It changed from uidb36 to uidb64 [in Django 1.6](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/releases/1.6/#django-contrib-auth-password-reset-uses-base-64-encoding-of-user-pk). It should be:

```
url(r'^reset/(?P<uidb64>[0-9A-Za-z_\-]+)/(?P<token>.+)/$',
'django.contrib.auth.views.password_reset_confirm',
name='password_reset_confirm'),
```

Update your password reset email template as well:

```
{% url 'password_reset_confirm' uidb64=uid token=token %}
```

In Django 1.8+, you should use the view in your url pattern rather than the string.

```
from django.contrib.auth.views import password_reset_confirm

urlpatterns = [
    ...
    url(r'^reset/(?P<uidb64>[0-9A-Za-z_\-]+)/(?P<token>.+)/$',
    password_reset_confirm, name='password_reset_confirm'),
    ...
]
```

Ensure that you